# Unexpected backend calls in Visual Studio when hovering over bookmarks in Opera

Tags: visual-studio, chromium, opera, bookmarks

I use Opera for web development in Visual Studio, and recently I've been experiencing unexpected backend calls when hovering over bookmarks. This issue is impacting my debugging process as unexpected breakpoints are triggered.

**Details:**

- Opera Version: 107.0.5045.36
- No browser extensions or plugins interfering.
- Backend calls occur when hovering over bookmarks, but no visual rendering takes place.

**Additional Information:**
I've already checked for browser extensions and plugins, but the issue persists. Can anyone provide insights into why this might be happening or suggest steps to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Any help is appreciated.